# Chomsky Normal Form for Integer Recognition

Tags: context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

If I have the following CFG, which is just the regex `[0-9]+`:

```
STATEMENT -> NUMBER
NUMBER -> NUMBER DIGIT
NUMBER -> DIGIT
DIGIT -> 0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9
```

How do I turn it into Chomskey Normal Form? It seems like its going to be impossible without using a `NUMBER -> epsilon` rule.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why it's not in CNF already??

Comment: Wait, is it valid CNF to have hypothetical rules `A -> B C` and `A -> a (terminal)`? In that case, it wouldn't be so bad.

Comment: So wait, this could just be done with `NUMBER -> NUMBER NUMBER` and `NUMBER -> 0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9`?

Comment: @EnjoysMath It is not in CNF because of the rules `STATEMENT-> NUMBER` and `NUMBER -> DIGIT`.

Comment: @user1978465 In order to turn a CF grammar into CNF, first you must get rid of unit variable productions. For this particular grammar, you'll see that when you get rid of unit variable productions, it will be in CNF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Chomsky normal form for the grammar is:

```
STATEMENT -> NUMBER
NUMBER -> NUMBER NUMBER
NUMBER -> 0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9
```

I don't know why this didn't occur to me earlier.